# Version of Mayer-Vietoris for closed subsets

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The following is a homework exercise that I've been stuck on for a couple of days. Any tips would be appreciated. Suppose that $X = A \cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are  closed sets. Suppose moreover that there exists two open subsets $U \subset A$ and $V \subset B$ that contains the intersection $Y=A \cap B$ such that the inclusions $Y \hookrightarrow U,V$ are homotopy equivalences. I'm trying to find some Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the homology groups of $X, A, B$ and $Y$.

Here is my attempt, which I think is a dead end... There exists a commutative diagram 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> C_{\bullet}(U \cap V) @>{}>> C_{\bullet}(U) \oplus C_{\bullet}(V) @>{}>> C_{\bullet}(U+V) @>{}>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>{}>> C_{\bullet}(Y) @>{}>> C_{\bullet}(A) \oplus C_{\bullet}(B) @>{}>> C_{\bullet}(A+B) @>{}>> 0\\
\end{CD},
$$
where the rows are short exact sequences of chain complexes, the vertical arrows are chain maps induced by inclusions, $C_{\bullet}(U+V)$ denotes the free abelian group generated by singular simplices with images contained in either $U$ or $V$, and similarly for $C_{\bullet}(A+B)$. Before we continue, we notice that $Y=U \cap C$, so the first vertical arrows is in fact the identity. By the zig-zag lemma, this commutative diagram induces a commutative diagram of long exact sequences of homology groups
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>{}>> H_{n}(Y) @>{}>> H_n(Y)^{\oplus2} @>{}>> H_n(U+V) @>{}>> H_{n-1}(Y) @>{}>> \cdots\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
\cdots @>{}>> H_n(Y) @>{}>> H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) @>{}>> H_n(A+B) @>{}>> H_{n-1}(Y) @>{}>>\cdots\\
\end{CD},
$$
where we have used the fact that $H_n(U), H_n(V) \cong H_n(Y)$, because of the homotopy equivalence $Y \hookrightarrow U,V$. Here is where I get stuck. If I could somehow show that $H_n(Y) \cong H_n(A)$, $H_n(Y) \cong H_n(B)$ and $H_n(U+V) \cong H_n(X)$, then I could use the five-lemma to show that $H_n(A + B) \cong H_n(X)$, however, I have no reason to expect the aforementioned isomorphisms to hold in general.

I've also tried to manipulate the sets $A,B,Y,U,V$ in order to force them into a Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but I haven't succeeded.